# Sahara service failed to start on Juno (python error)

Tags: python, openstack, keystore

I installed opnstack Juno on centos 7 and its working fine. But when I installed sahara using this link. It installed without error but when i was run this command

sahara-all --config-file /etc/sahara/sahara.conf

it showed lots of errors to start sahara api with openstack.

Here are the details about this error, I am not able to figure it out, kindly help me with this.

```
[root@controller controller]# sahara-all --config-file /etc/sahara/sahara.conf 
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.060 6548 INFO sahara.main [-] Starting Sahara all-in-one
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.060 6548 INFO sahara.utils.rpc [-] Notifications disabled
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.378 6548 INFO sahara.plugins.base [-] Plugin 'vanilla' loaded sahara.plugins.vanilla.plugin:VanillaProvider
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.378 6548 INFO sahara.plugins.base [-] Plugin 'hdp' loaded sahara.plugins.hdp.ambariplugin:AmbariPlugin
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.378 6548 INFO sahara.plugins.base [-] Plugin 'spark' loaded sahara.plugins.spark.plugin:SparkProvider
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.437 6548 DEBUG sahara.main [-] Logging of request/response exchange could be enabled using flag --log-exchange make_app /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/main.py:144
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.438 6548 INFO keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Starting keystone auth_token middleware
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.442 6548 INFO keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Using /tmp/keystone-signing-SB6l5s as cache directory for signing certificate
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.442 6548 INFO sahara.main [-] Loading 'all-in-one' ops
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.443 6548 DEBUG sahara.service.periodic [-] Starting periodic tasks with initial delay '18' seconds setup /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/service/periodic.py:152
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.443 6548 INFO sahara.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task check_for_zombie_proxy_users because its interval is negative
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.444 6548 INFO sahara.main [-] Loading 'direct' infrastructure engine
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.466 6548 INFO sahara.main [-] Loading 'ssh' remote
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 CRITICAL sahara [-] error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara Traceback (most recent call last):
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara   File "/bin/sahara-all", line 10, in <module>
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara     sys.exit(main())
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/cli/sahara_all.py", line 60, in main
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara     wsgi.server(eventlet.listen((cfg.CONF.host, cfg.CONF.port), backlog=500),
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 39, in listen
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara     sock.bind(addr)
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
        2015-11-29 00:27:24.467 6548 TRACE sahara   [root@controller controller]#
```

Answer (score 1):

See the error `[Errno 98] Address already in use`, it means the port has already been occupied, use `ls -i:PORT` to find the process, and then kill it or Just change another port in your config file.